# How to raise ActionController::UnpermittedParameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, actioncontroller

I am whitelisting some parameters like

```
params.permit(:a, :b)
```

If someone sends some other query parameters in request, i am getting "UnpermitterParameters" exception as i have add this to my app config

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

But while processing the query parameters if i get some invalid value for a key i want to raise the same exception.

When i do

```
raise ActionController::UnpermittedParameters "found unexpected parameter: c"
```

I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `UnpermittedParameters' for ActionController:Module
```

Can we raise the same exception ourselves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have found the answer.

We should used like below:

```
raise ActionController::UnpermittedParameters.new [:c]
```